# Incomplete htaccess for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not sure if it can be done and I've looked high and low. It's possible I'm just not constructing the search query correctly to yield the results I need.

I have 2 domains with differing content on a host (one added onto the other). When I added the second domain on, all 3 of these scenarios would resolve:

(1) domain2.domain1.com 
(2) domain1.com/domain2/ 
(3) www.domain2.domain1.com 
(4) www.domain1.com/domain2/ 
(5) domain2.com

I only want to show content for https://domain1.com or https://domain2.com -but- 
https://domain1.com/domain2/ and  https://www.domain1.com/domain2/ should resolve to https://domain2.com

The following changes to the .htaccess took care of scenario (1) & (3) but I cannot figure out how to handle scenarios (2) & (4):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.domain1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Diamich. Welcome to the Stack Overflow community. I have provided the solution for your question. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem up vote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **four** virtual hosts, **< VirtualHost >**, for the same.

For **domain1.com**, you need to create a virtual host that redirect the **http to https** and another one that will take care of **https connections**.
Similarly for the **domain2.com**

**ServerName** and **ServerAlias** directives will help you in your problem (**Name based virtual host**).

More can be read for the same at [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)

Now your file will contain the below rules

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.23.34:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com

    Redirect permanent / https://domain1.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.23.34:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com

    Redirect permanent / https://domain2.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.23.34:443>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain2
    RewriteRule (.*) https://domain2.com/ [L,R=301,NC]

    // ssl certificate setting for the same

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.23.34:443>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain1
    RewriteRule (.*) https://domain1.com/ [L,R=301,NC]

    // ssl certificate setting for the same

</VirtualHost>
```

Please make sure to restart the apache.

After this rule

1. www.domain1.com will redirect to https://domain1.com
2. domain1.com will redirect to https://domain1.com
3. www.domain2.com will redirect to https://domain2.com
4. domain2.com will redirect to https://domain2.com
5. https://domain1.com/domain2 will redirect to https://domain2.com
6. https://domain2.com/domain1 will redirect to https://domain1.com
7. https://www.domain1.com/domain2 will redirect to https://domain2.com
8. https://www.domain2.com/domain1 will redirect to https://domain1.com

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I could probably figure out how to do all of that if I had a virtual server, but I opted to do shared hosting because I'm really not qualified to keep a server secure. Since my websites will have ecommerce, I didn't want to take the risk.

Given that I'm on shared hosting, is there any other way to keep the search engines from crawling those areas and penalizing me for duplicate content. They don't always obey robot.txt